# Git and NetBeans - need to add

Tags: git, netbeans

I am using Git with NetBeans and am having an issue with a recent project. I started out by running git in the terminal to retrieve a repository. I then added an upstream and finally added this project in NetBeans.

The problem now is that I have to use add prior to any commit, otherwise NetBeans will not find any files that should be committed. Why is this and is there anything I can do to fix this?

I have used Git with NetBeans before without this issue but then I might have added the projects/repositories another way.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I don't know why that happened. But if you use the terminal (git bash) and you can't add, commit or push your code. Then you can use git reset --hard HEAD, but beware save your code somewhere else first (for example in a text file). Because that command removes all your uncommitted code! And it will revert to your previous commit.

If that doesn't work, you can clone it again. And maybe that will fix your problem.

Comment: I have no clue either what is going on :) I have tried git reset and also cloning the repo once again but nothing changes. I still have to use add every time before commit. It's not a disaster of course but it feels a bit unnecessary. This only happens on my Windows PC, on my Mac (also using Netbeans) I don't have to use add.

Comment: Well if you are using a  Git GUI then I don't know if you have to use 'add'. But if you use git bash (a terminal) then you have to do three things:

1. git add (this adds all the changes you have made in your project)
2. git commit (this will give you the opportunity to write a short description of the changes you had made)
3. git push origin (this is the name of your remote) master (name of the branch)  (this will push the commit to your repository on the server)